# How can I fix "Expected resource of type id" error?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an error in android studio 4.1.1
I want make image"student_bg" draggable so I added this code and it didn't worked.

this is my tutorial.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/character"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/student_bg" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my tutorial.kt

```
var moveX = 0f
var moveY = 0f

class tutorial : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial)

    val st = findViewById<ImageView>(R.drawable.student_bg)

    st.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        when(event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                moveX = v.x - event.rawX
                moveY = v.y - event.rawY
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                v.animate()
                        .x(event.rawX + moveX)
                        .y(event.rawY + moveY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start()
            }
        }
        true
    }
}
}
```

I found create ids.xml will help this issue, but it didn't worked.
[I made ids.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RXUZ.png)

This is my .xml file: [tutorial.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJy0F.png)

And this is my .kt file: [turotial.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7QvI.png)

Did I missed something?
Why it didn't work?

edit: this is my imports:

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.KeyEvent.*
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.Random
import kotlin.properties.Delegates
```

[import(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjfNk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tutorials.kt, instead of "R.drawable.student_bg", replace it with "R.id.character", because findViewById required an id, but you are passing an drawable and **delete the ids.xml too**